# How to set a Condition for Movable Row

Tags: tabulator

In Tabulator.js V 4.3 i can set MovableRows = true or false. I need to create a condition for deny or permit the moving of specific row.
Someone have a solution?

Comment: You cannot set it for each row it works for all or none

Answer (score 0):

Have not tested but I suppose you could set rowHandle:
http://tabulator.info/docs/4.3/move#rows

Then do something like:

`rowMouseEnter:function(e, row){if (Number(row.getCell("age").getValue()) < 20){row.getCell("handle").getColumn().hide()}else{row.getCell("handle").getColumn().show()}},`